# How to make this statement loop multiple times

Tags: ruby

How do I make this statement run 26 times

```
player_a.add_to_top(orig_deck.deal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Integer.html#method-i-times):

```
26.times {player_a.add_to_top(orig_deck.deal)}
```